# infinitely many solutions to $\displaystyle x^n + y^n = z^{n+1}$

Tags: number-theory

Let $n$ be a positive integer.  Show that the equation

$\displaystyle x^n + y^n = z^{n+1}$

has infinitely many integer solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theorem : $x^n+y^n=z^{n+1}$

Let $p$ is an integer and $q$ is another integer.

\begin{equation}
  \left\{
      \begin{aligned}
        &p^n+q^n = k\\
        &OR\\
        &(p^n+q^n)(p^n+q^n)^n= k^{n+1}\\
        &OR\\
        &(p(p^n+q^n))^n+(q(p^n+q^n))^n= k^{n+1}\\
      \end{aligned}
    \right.
\end{equation}

Let $p(p^n+q^n)=x$ and $q(p^n+q^n)=y$ and $k=z$

$x^n+y^n=z^{n+1}$ (Proved)

Answer (score 2):

Hint: It is pretty easy to find infinitely many with $x|y$.

Comment: So, let y = x*m.  Then x^n + (x*m)^n = x^n + (x^n)*(m^n) = (x^n)*((m^n) + 1) = z*z^n.....   Is this the jist of it?  THen you could say that if m^n + 1 = z for all m,n in Z and if x|y, then there are infinitely many solution?

Comment: @ChristopherErnst So, now can you find a specific $x$ given $m$? It's sort of a generalization of the obviojus solution $x=y=z=2$

Comment: So I'm thinking since we have this x^n(1+ m^n) = z^n *z, if z = 1 + m^n and x|y such that y = xm we can find an infinite amount of solutions since there are infinitely many m's to try?

Comment: If you wanted $Ax^n$ to be a power of $n+1$ what is the most obvious value you could choose for $x$?

Comment: There are also some other infinite classes that are perhaps even more obvious - cases when $y=0$.

Comment: You would choose x = A since A* A^n = A^(n+1).  Ahhhhhh.  Darned assumptions.  I assumed i was looking for x, y and z solutions (which I am), but even for the obvious x=y=z=2, since n is a natural number there are infinitely many n's that satisfy 2^n + 2^n = 2*2^n = 2^n+1.

Comment: No $x=y=z=2$ isn't enough, since that is only one solution for each $n$.

Comment: So, above you had $(m^n+1)x^n = z^{n+1}$. What is $A$? What is $x$? What is $z$?

Comment: so so they all equal m^n + 1

Comment: So $(x,y,z)=(m^n+1,m(m^n+1),m^n+1)$ for any integer $m$.

Comment: That's what I meant, i meant that A=x=z.  I just couldn't get passed that.

Comment: I suppose an easier hint would have been that there are infinitely many solutions with $x=z$. :) @ChristopherErnst

Answer (score 0):

Let $x$ and $y$ be such that $x \mid y$.  This means that $y = x \cdot m$ where $m$ is a positive integer.
Thus
$x^n + y^n = x^n + (x \cdot m)^n = x^n + x^n \cdot m^n = x^n \cdot [1 + m^n] = z \cdot z^n = z^{n+1}$

So we know that when $x \mid y$, we have $x^n \cdot [1 + m^n] = z^n \cdot z$
Now let $x^n = z^n$.  Thus $1 + m^n = z$
Then $z^n = [1 + m^n]^n = x^n$.

Substituting $[1 + m^n]^n$ for $x^n$ we get
$$x^n + y^n = [1 + m^n]^n + (m[1 + m^n])^n = [1 + m^n]^n + m^n \cdot [1 + m^n]^n
 \\ = [1 + m^n] \cdot [1 + m^n]^n = [1 + m^n]^{n+1} = x^{n+1} = z^{n+1}$$

Since there are infinitely many choices for $m$ since $n$ is a positive integer, we have our answer;  a triple that gives infinitely many solutions to the equation

$x^n + y^n = z^{n+1}$

is $(1 + m^n, m \cdot (1 + m^n), 1 + m^n)$.