# $a^x + b^y = c^z \Rightarrow a^{x-2} + b^{y-2} = 0 $ (mod c) if $x,y,z > 2$ and $a,b,c$ are pairwise coprime?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $a,b,c,x,y,z$ be positive integers such that $x,y,z > 2$ and $a$,$b$,$c$ are pairwise coprime.
Suppose it is given that $a^x + b^y = c^z$ (i.e $a^x + b^y \equiv 0 (\text{mod } c)$), then is it true that $a^{x-2} + b^{y-2} \equiv 0 (\text{mod } c)$ ? If not, could you give a counterexample?

I tried to looking manually for counterexamples in special equations like $x^n + y^n = z^{n+1}$ and $x^n + y^{n+1} = z^{n+2}$, but there weren't any for these special equations.

Source: This question was asked in one of the FB groups I am in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a trick question. Note the [Beal Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beal_conjecture) says that $A^x + B^y = C^z$ has no solution

> in positive integers $A, B, C, x, y, z$ with $A, B,$ and $C$ being pairwise coprime and all of $x, y, z$ being greater than $2$

There's been extensive computer checks done so far and a US million dollar prize for its proof or disproof is on offer, so I don't believe your FB group would know of any such values existing.

However, assume hypothetically the Beal Conjecture is wrong and there are such values. Then

$$a^x + b^y \equiv 0 \pmod c \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

Without knowing what the specific values of $a,b,c,x,y$ and $z$ are, it's not possible to definitively prove or disprove that

$$a^{x-2} + b^{y-2} \equiv 0 \pmod c \tag{2}\label{eq2}$$

is always true. Nonetheless, given that \eqref{eq1} holds, the following provides an analysis on some of the conditions required for \eqref{eq2} to be true. In particular, it requires that

$$a^x + a^2b^{y - 2} \equiv 0 \pmod c \\
-b^y + a^2b^{y - 2} \equiv 0 \pmod c \\
a^2 \equiv b^2 \pmod c \\
a \equiv \pm b \pmod c \tag{3}\label{eq3}$$

For $a \equiv b$, you get

$$b^{x-2} + b^{y-2} \equiv 0 \pmod c \tag{4}\label{eq4}$$

while for $a \equiv -b$, you get

$$(-b)^{x-2} + b^{y-2} \equiv 0 \pmod c \tag{5}\label{eq5}$$

If $x = y$, then \eqref{eq4} becomes $2b^{x-2} \equiv 0 \pmod c$ which is only true if $c = 2$, and likewise with \eqref{eq5} if $x$ is even. If $x$ is odd, then \eqref{eq5} will always be true. If $x \neq y$, then WLOG, let $y \gt x$, say $y = x + n$ for $n \gt 0$. Then after dividing by $b^{x-2}$, \eqref{eq4}, and \eqref{eq5} if $x$ is even, become

$$1 + b^n \equiv 0 \pmod c \tag{6}\label{eq6}$$

while for $x$ odd, \eqref{eq5} becomes

$$-1 + b^n \equiv 0 \pmod c \tag{7}\label{eq7}$$

Both such cases are possible for various values of $b, n$ and $c$.

Overall, the required conditions for \eqref{eq2} to be true are relatively stringent, so I believe it's unlikely for it to always be true, but I don't see any way to rule out this possibility.

Comment: The equations which you found on assuming the result is true is correct. However it is not true there are no such values of $a,b,c,x,y,z$. I think you misread the Beal Conjecture: it requires that $a,b$ and $c$ to have a common prime factor. Here their gcd is $1$. A few possible examples:
$x^n + y^{n} = z^{n+1}$ is a special case of above equation - and this mathstack link proves that this special equation has infinite solutions. (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/309386/infinitely-many-solutions-to-displaystyle-xn-yn-zn1)

Comment: The overall logic of the proof does not answer the question. You have shown that there are solutions that satisfy both equations (a) and (b) where equation (a) is $a^x+b^y \equiv 0$ mod $c^z$ and equation (b) is $a^{x-2}+b^{y-2} \equiv 0$ mod $c$. To answer the question, you would need to show either (1) that any solution to (a), is also *necessarily* a solution to (b), OR (2) a solution to $a^x+b^y = c^z$ that is not a solution to (b).

Comment: @Kaind The Beal Conjecture says your equation **only** holds when there's a common prime factor. On that page, it even restates it as being equivalent to "There are **no** solutions to the above equation in positive integers $A,B,C,x,y,z$ with $A,B,$ and $C$ being pairwise coprime and all of $x,y,z$ being greater than $2$". As for your suggestion and link, all of the provided solutions show cases where the $x,y,z$ are **not** pairwise coprime, so they don't apply to your case.

Comment: @Mike I believe you misread my solution. As I stated, there are no current known solutions to $a^x + b^y = c^z$ where $x,y,z$ at all $\gt 2$ and $a,b,c$ are pairwise coprime positive integers, as stated in the Beal conjecture. As such, if the conjecture is not true, it's unknown what the properties of $a$ and $b$ will be relative to $c$ apart from $a^x + b^y = c^z$. What I've done is provide several possibilities, to show $a^{x-2} + b^{y-2} \equiv 0 \pmod c$ may or not be true. Without knowing more, I can't (nor can anyone else) conclusively say whether or not it's always true.

Comment: @Mike I've add some more details & explanations to my answer to hopefully make it clearer.

Comment: @JohnOmielan I am still not seeing Equations (6) and (7). In particular what if $n$ is 0? And yes I get that the Beal conjecture is hard and won't be proved or disproved here, but that doesn't mean *a prori* that the OP's statement cant be proved or disproved i.e., if there were such $A,B,C,x,y,z$ then $A,B,C,x,y,z$ must also satisfy... I do think you should make clear in your answer that this isn't a proof or a disproof of the OP's statement, just why you think that OP's statment sn't always true. (As going by what you had written I was expecting to see a proof or disproof)

Comment: @Mike Thank you for your feedback. I basically stated I was just giving conditions on how what the OP asked about could be true in any case, not in all cases, but I have added some extra comments to hopefully make this more clear. As for my equations (6) and (7), first note that $n$ is always positive as stated previously. Also, I added explicitly that I get those equations by dividing by $b^{x-2}$, i.e., multiplying by $b^{-1}$ $x-2$ times. As $y = x + n$, this leaves the $b^{y-2}$ term as being $b^n$.

Comment: @JohnOmielan I see (6) and (7) now....I should have before, they do follow right from (4) and (5)...thanks!