# $x^{n+1} +y^{n}=z^{n}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that $x^{n+1} +y^{n}=z^{n}$ has an infinite number of nonzero natural solutions for any natural number $n\geq2$ .

I used the $a^{n} -b^{n}=(a-b)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+a^{n-3}b^2+...+a^2b^{n-3}+ab^{n-2}+b^{n-1})$ formula and now have this: $x^{n+1}=(z-y)(z^{n-1}+z^{n-2}y+z^{n-3}y^2+...+z^2y^{n-3}+zy^{n-2}+y^{n-1})$

I don't know what to do next, any help is appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: See [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/309386/infinitely-many-solutions-to-displaystyle-xn-yn-zn1). We can replace $y$ by $-y$ for $n$ odd to obtain our equation.

Answer (score 4):

Dividing both sides by $x^n$ and put $y/x=b,\ z/x=c$.
Then $x=c^n-b^n$ and $y=b(c^n-b^n),\ z=c(c^n-b^n)$. Thus we obtained a parametric solution. It is obvious that there are infinitely many $b,c$ whose $x,y,z$ become nonzero positive integers.